# logical short-circuit and lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda, short-circuiting

I have the following lambda expression:

```
response = allDescendants
        .Where(n =>
        n.Caption.Contains(query) ||
        n.Identifier.ToString().Contains(query) ||
        n.Type.ToString().Contains(query) ||
        n.Path.Contains(query) ||
        n.Description.Contains(query) ||
        (n.KeyWords != null && n.KeyWords.Any(kw => kw.Contains(query))) ||
        n.SubType.Contains(query) ||
        n.GroupingBy.Contains(query)
        ).ToList();
```

in the class definition the keyWord field is set to null:

```
private string[] keyWords = null;
public string[] KeyWords
{
    get { return keyWords; }
    set { keyWords = value; }
}
```

The line `(n.KeyWords != null && n.KeyWords.Any(kw => kw.Contains(query)))` throws a NullReferenceException because the the KeyWord field is null, but I was under the impression that since the check for null happened before the lambda, the entire expression should short-circuit to false. Is this something specific to do with lambdas or something else I'm not getting?

Edit:

I have found the culprit, it was a constructor that sets the string array to string[1] instead of null.

Comment: are you sure the Keywords is null and not one of the Keywords ?

Comment: How do you know that it's null? Since it is short-circuiting another reason could be that the collection contains one item that is null which causes a `NullReferenceException` at `kw.Contains`.

Comment: One of the keywords is definitely `null`. Change `kw.Contains(query)` to `kw != null && kw.Contains(query)` and you should be fine. Good usage of Step In and Step Out in the debugger will show you that `n.KeyWords` is indeed not null, and you'll be able to identify all the null entries of the collection. I would worry more about why they're there in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone in the comments suggested, I have looked for a code path that sets elements of my array to null instead of the entire array and have found it. It now sets the entire array to null and the code works as intended.

Comment: Don't answer your own question like this. There's no value to the SO community. You should delete the question instead.

Comment: @Enigmativity sure, if your comment gets enough up votes ill definitely delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger just marks that whole line. `n.KeyWords` was not null since, indeed, `&&` short-circuits. (Or, that `KeyWords` property returns non-null the first time and null the second time it is called!)

Look at the call stack to see in what method the crash actually happened. The lambda will be on top and use can use the debugger to examine the value of `kw` which will be null.